# Post json formatted file and csv formatted file with curl to springboot endpoint

Tags: json, spring-boot, csv, curl, post

I am trying to post a json formatted file and csv formatted file using a curl command.
Here is my spring boot endpoint:

```
@PostMapping
public MyDTO registerMyEntity(
        @RequestBody MyDTO myDTO ,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {...}
```

My json file myJsonFile.json contains this:

```
{
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "key2"
}
```

and my csv file myCSVFile contains this:

```
key3;key4
value3;value4
```

I used this curl (after having tried many many many ones):

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -d @./import.json -F 'file=@./import.csv;text/csv' http://localhost:8080/path/to/endpoint
```

but no way...
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you please post the response, that you get after executing the curl command?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://ip:port/url/to/endpoint' \
--form 'dataSetCourses=@"path/to/csv/file"' \
--form 'newDataSet=@"path/to/json/file"'
```

Where the endpoint has been modified as follow:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public MyDTO registerMyEntity(@RequestPart MyDto newDataSet,
            @RequestPart MultipartFile dataSetCourses) {...}
```